# Is there a way to measure the "sharpness" of a decision boundary of a CNN?

Tags: neural-network

It is commonly seen as something bad if the decision boundary of a neural network is too sharp, meaning if slight changes in the input change the class prediction completely.

Given a trained CNN, is it possible to measure / calculate the "sharpness" of its decision boundaries? Did somebody do that already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might enjoy looking into the literature on "adversarial examples".  Given an instance $x$ with a label $y$, an adversarial example is a (typically carefully constructed) instance $x'$ that is very similar to $x$, but whose label differs from $y$.  The research literature suggests that it is often possible to find adversarial examples that are very close to the original $x$.  You could use the distance $d(x,x')$ as a measure of sharpness of the decision boundary near $x$; or you could average this over many $x$ to get a global measure of sharpness.

There are many methods for finding adversarial examples.  A standard simple one is the gradient sign method, originally described in the following paper:

Ian J. Goodfellow, Jonathon Shlens, Christian Szegedy. [Explaining and harnessing adversarial examples](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.6572). [arXiv:1412.6572](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.6572), 2014.

Since then there have been numerous improvements that find even closer adversarial examples, e.g., iterative gradient sign (arxiv:1607.02533), Deepfool (arxiv:1511.04599), and others.  You might also be interested in  [Cleverhans](https://github.com/openai/cleverhans), a software library to assist with finding adversarial examples.

Comment: @MartinThoma, OK, if this doesn't answer the question, could you clarify what the question is?  I was thinking you asked for a measure of sharpness, and this answer proposes a possible measure of sharpness, but perhaps I have misunderstood?

Comment: Sorry, I miss-read the important part of your answer. Yes, I think this could work. Finding such a $x'$ is a potential problem, though. Or at least it adds one degree of freedom.

Comment: Could you add one paper which gives a simple procedure how to find adverserial examples? E.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.1897 might be a good example

Comment: @MartinThoma, done -- see edited answer.